# Splitting lines from a text file in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to using split line on a text file that looks like this:

```
12/1 AH120 LAX PEK 12:30 21:00
12/2 C32 PEK HNA 12:40 20:00
12/3 D34 MON DOE 3:00 4:00
12/5 A100 ICS SEL 4:00 12:00
```

Here is the code :

```
f = open('flights.txt', 'r')

for line in f:
    x = f.readline()
    y = x.split()
    print(y)
```

The problem I have is that instead of giving me lists of each line, it skips a few lines and the output is such that is looks like this:

```
['12/2', 'C32', 'PEK', 'HNA', '12:40', '20:00']
['12/3', 'D34', 'MON', 'DOE', '3:00', '4:00']
```

As you can see it is missing the lines beginning with 12/1 and 12/5.
I don't know why I am running into this problem. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're reading a line using `for line in f` already. Then, you read a line using `f.readline` and use that, but skip the one in `line`. Therefore, you're missing out on some of the lines

```
for line in f:
    y = line.split()
    print(y)
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `for line in f` already read lines one by one. Use it like this:

```
with open('flights.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        y = line.split()
        print(y)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. If you know any better way to format the data in the  file so that it can work within kinds of programs that need to display it back to the user and can be sortablle, that would be helpful too!

Comment: Using `from operator import itemgetter`, you could specify on which column of your list of lists you want to sort in the `sort()` function.